# What aggregator element represents the image in a feed?

Tags: media, feeds

I have an RSS feed from a partner that I link to from my menu.

If I link directly to the XML page -- http://www.criticalblast.com/sync-collaboration.xml -- then it will display the full feed with the attendant thumbnail image and links.  However, doing this takes the user outside the structure of the website, and they have to hit BACK to return to it. (This link does not work for all browsers, either -- some of them will dump the XML, some, like IE 11, Firefox, will actually format and display it.)

I have created a Page to display selected elements of the Aggregator feed -- http://www.criticalblast.com/sync-aggregator -- while staying within the structure of the site. I'm 99% happy with that, but I'd love to get the thumbnail images included. Of the list of aggregator items that I can include when modifying my view, I don't see anything jumping out at me that seems to be the thumbnail image. Anyone have any success with this in the past?

SUMMARY: I can see thumbnail image in feed, I cannot see it in Page display format.

Thanks!